# NSNumberFormatter is rounding off currency amount for some currencies

Tags: ios

I need to format a number along with currency symbol , i am using following code. Issue i am facing is that number is getting rounded to 34.80 , and this happens only for some currencies , if i change currency code to "INR" in the code below than result shows amount without rounding.

```
NSDecimalNumber *num = (NSDecimalNumber*)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:34.78f];
NSString *curr = @"CHF";

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.currencyCode = curr;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into [Swedish rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_rounding)! The Swiss franc is only issued in denominations down to 0.05 Francs. By convention, displayed prices are rounded to the nearest boundary multiple of 0.05 upon display. The Wikipedia page I linked to contains examples of other currencies that use such rounding, with various multiples including 0.05, 0.1, 0.25 and 0.5.